# chained hash table keys with universal hasing,does it need a rehash?

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable, universal

I am implementing a chained hash table using a vector < lists  >. I resized my vector to a prime number, let's say 5. To choose the key I am using the universal hasing.

My question is, do I need to rehash my vector? I mean this code will generate always a key in a range between 0 and 5 because it depends from the size of my hashtable, causing collisions of course but the new strings will be all added in the lists of every position in the vector...so it seems I don't need to resize/rehash the whole thing. What do you think? Is this a mistake?

Comment: If you have a vector of size 5, then index 5 is out of bounds.

Comment: Also, I recommend you pass the vector by constant reference, otherwise it will be *copied* every time you call the function.

Comment: the vector is empty at the beginning and I will insert strings at runtime. why is 5 out of bounds? everything is calculatd %5 no?

Comment: But when you call the function when the vector is *not* empty? Sooner of later you will have lots of data in the lists in the vector, and if you pass the vector by value all of the data will be copied causing quite a lot of overhead. As for the indexing issue, vectors are similar to arrays in that indexes are zero-based, meaning the valid indexes for a vector of size 5 is `0` to `4` (inclusive). Yes the modulo operator will give you the correct result but the text in the question can be interpreted as you include `5` in the indexing.

Comment: Oh and by the way, if you use `unsigned int` then you don''t need the check for negative numbers, just let the value wrap around if the maximum `unsigned int` value is reached.

Comment: ok thank you, will work on those changes!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do. Otherwise objects will be in the wrong hash bucket and when you search for them, you won't find them. The whole point of hashing is to make locating an object faster -- that won't work if objects aren't where they're supposed to be.

By the way, you probably shouldn't be doing this. There are people who have spent years developing efficient hashing algorithms. Trying to roll your own will result in poor performance. Start with the article on [linear hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_hashing) in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

> do I need to rehash my vector?

Your container could continue to function without rehashing, but searching, insertions and erasing will perform more and more like a plain `list` instead of a hash table: for example, if you've inserted 10,000 elements you can expect each `list` in your `vector` to have roundly 2000 elements, and you may have to search all 2000 to see if a value you're considering inserting is a duplicate, or to find a value to `erase`, or simply return an `iterator` to.  Sure, 2,000 is better than 10,000, but it's a long way from the O(1) performance expected of a quality hash table implementation.  Your non-resizing implementation is still "O(N)".

> Is this a mistake?

Yes, a fundamental one.